# DSpace: PostgreSQL query not working properly

Tags: postgresql, dspace

I'm trying to find all the colections that has a name. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM collection WHERE name='mycollection';
```

The name I'm querying has two 'instances' on the database. However just one are being returned. I'm sure they have the exactly string name.
Any suggestions why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the DSpace schema varies from release to release, it would be good to include your version number as well.

Try the following to see if you have some white space in the name field.

SELECT * FROM collection WHERE like='%mycollection%'

Comment: The version I'm using is 4.4. By the way using this query it returns the two instances. I thought they had exactly the same string name. Thanks!